# What is the round to two decimals of the number 33408.55446000001?

Tags: rounding-error

Is it 33408.55 or 33408.56 ?

I would have gone towards the .56 but every online round calculator give me .55 ...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's closer to $33408.55$ than to $33408.56$ (check the difference)

Comment: It's $.55$, since $4<5$

Answer (score 2):

.55 is the correct answer since 4 is less than 5

Comment: lol literally a dupe of my comment.

Comment: Haha sorry didn't see it till I posted @DonThousand

Comment: So, there is no spreading ? Since the 4 to the complete right becomes a 5, then this new 5 is bigger or equal to 5 then spread to the other 4 to the left etc ?

Comment: Well since you only want to round to 2 decimal places you look at the third decimal, if this is greater than 5 you round up if not the 2 decimals remain the same @ThomasLeclerc

Comment: Ohhh, I see it now, wow, I feel a bit stupid ahaha, thanks all <3

Comment: Special consideration should be paid to numbers which end in trailing nines... $0.499999\dots$ will in fact round *up*, not down, for exactly the same reason that $0.5$ rounds up since they are after all equal as numbers.

Comment: @DonThousand: That should teach you not to write answers as comments. ;-)

Comment: @HansLundmark Come on, answering this sort of question is rep-hunting.